# Convert DAO extraBalance to Ether or Bitcoin

Tags: ether, tokens, the-dao, myetherwallet, thedao-refund

I'm a noob in cryptocurrencies and *still* hold some DAO_extraBalance tokens in MyEtherWallet. I want to convert these DAO_extraBalance tokens into Ether tokens (ETH) or Bitcoins (BTC). 
I've browsed through some old messages and found that support to convert DAO_extraBalance tokens to ETH or BTC halted via MyEtherWallet, Jaxx and Poloniex.

Furthermore, other options are quite complex, such as issuing an ExtraBalDaoWithdraw contract via:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x755cdba6AE4F479f7164792B318b2a06c759833B#code.

I hope anyone can help me out with a step-by-step procedure - for dummies - how to convert DAO_extraBalance to ETH or BTC. A YouTube video with such a procedure would also help. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- Download dist-v3.3.7.zip from [MyEtherWallet v3.3.7](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.3.7) to your computer drive
- Unzip the dist-v3.3.7.zip file
- Double click on index.html
- Click on the Withdraw DAO at the bottom of the page
- Upload your Keystore File (UTC / JSON) and you will see the following screen (there are 0 refunds for the account shown):

Read more: https://medium.com/curator-multisig-phf-official-channel/dao-token-holders-come-claim-your-money-b428f186572a

See also: https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Withdraw_The_DAO_Refunds.3F